# Sharing Entity Framework models with other projects using MEF

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, mef, abstraction, composition

I am currently developing a Windows service and I am am looking to use MEF to compose all of the services components at run time. The data access module (project) is using Entity Framework 4.1 and a Domain Service Class to perform CRUD operations on the entity model.

The problem I have is how to share the models outside the DAL project when composing the DAL into the worker class in the main project.

For exmaple this is one of the methods in the DAL contract interface

```
Function GetInspectionFaults() As IQueryable(Of InspectionFault)
```

This interface is currently in the DAL project (not the shared/referenced project containing the other contract interfaces) as it needs references to the entity model for the POCO types.

How do I shared these POCO types?

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it might be a bit more work, you might want to consider having a separate set of models (view models if you will) that you have in a shared assembly (maybe a common/contracts assembly). This would enable your parts to utilise a common set of types which are not explicitly dependent on your DAL.

In regards to separation of concerns, I wouldn't recommend exporting your DAL directly, but provide an abstraction to it via something like the Repository pattern. A repository will handle the communication with the DAL and mapping from your domain to your view models.

You can export and import your repository wherever you need it, which means your parts are not dependent on a specific data source. This makes your code more robust, and more testable.